# Ideal Accept Rate for a GIS StackExchange User

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, accepted-answer

What is the ideal Accept Rate for a GIS StackExchange user?  I understand the importance of keeping the overall Accept Rate above 90%, but how much of a concern should that be to a typical user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An individual accept rate doesn't have to be anything like 90%. The accept rate percentage is shown to make people aware of the feature and encourage users to accept answers.

From [New Question Asker Features](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/):

> It is considered good manners to accept answers on your questions, eventually, but accepting answers is not required. I personally consider anything at 70% or over quite good, meaning you accept answers on 7 out of 10 questions that you ask. There are certainly cases where you don’t get an answer you like, or the question is inherently unanswerable.

That is *not* to say that 69% and below is a somehow a "failing grade."

Answer (score 4):

I've seen 70% floating around various quesions on meta.stackoverflow.com.  I personally would  read or answer a question regardless of the rate.  Maybe that will change as the gis.stackexchange.com grows and matures.

Some users simply ask hard(*but good*) questions and it drops their acceptance rate([Kirk Kuykendall](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/59/kirk-kuykendall) comes to mind).  I think it's fine because news of [gis.stackexchange.com](http://gis.stackexchange.com) is still propagating through the GIS community and maybe you'll get that answer when the person who does know the answer signs up and provides it.